# How do you remove this text in vb net?

Tags: vb.net, file, filestream

Whenever I use streamwriter to put a textbox value into a .txt file it goes like this:
`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: dadadadaad` what is wrong here?

```
Dim Na_1 As New IO.StreamWriter(folder & "\name.txt")
Na_1.WriteLine(TextName)
Na_1.Close()
```

Comment: give us some code otherwise it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Assuming TextName is the name of your textbox: try Na_1.WriteLine(TextName.Text)

Comment: Do a google search for `VB.NET Option Strict On` - then switch it on. This will stop these sorts of errors compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `flush` the `StreamWriter` before you close it:

```
Na_1.Flush()
```

> Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered **data to be written** to the underlying stream.

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So this should be your code:

```
Na_1 As New IO.StreamWriter(folder & "\name.txt")
Na_1.WriteLine(TextName)
Na_1.Flush()
Na_1.Close()
```

Alternatively you can use the `Using`-statement which automatically flushes and closes the stream (this is the **better practice**):

```
Using Na_1 As New IO.StreamWriter(folder & "\name.txt")
   Na_1.WriteLine(TextName)
End Using
```

---

Following the comments of Ric and ForkAndBeard I think I misunderstood the problem:

Your problem is that you are calling the `TextName`object of the `TextBox`-Class directly via `Na_1.WriteLine(TextName)`.
Now since you can't write an object to a file, the runtime simply call the `ToString()`-method of the Class `TextBox` which inherits from `Object`.
The result will be following:

> "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: "

or generally:

> "YourNamespace.YourClass"

Source:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If you want to have the text of the TextBox, you have to call the property `TextBox.Text` of the object:

```
Na_1.WriteLine(TextName.Text);
```

Comment: wrap the StreamWriter in a using statement

Comment: I think the issue is the fact that the .Text property of the TextBox is not being used.